# Generalization of Minkowski's inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $$\mathcal{M}_\phi(x)=\phi^{-1}\left(\sum_i q_i \phi(x_i)\right)$$ where $x=x_1,...x_n$ is a sequence of positive, real numbers, $\sum q_i=1$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ is a twice continuously differentiable function with $\phi(\cdot)>0$, $\phi'(\cdot)>0$ and $\phi''(\cdot)<0$.

I would like to know whether it can be proved that

$$\mathcal{M}_\phi(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \ge \alpha \mathcal{M}_\phi(x) + (1-\alpha)\mathcal{M}_\phi(y)$$

with $\alpha \in (0,1)$. That is, I'm looking for a particular generalization of Minkowski's inequality and have so far struck out.

I doubt the above is true in general, so alternatively under what conditions on $\phi(\cdot)$ and the $q_i$ will it be true.